# How to Implement a Create() Function for Derived Classes in C++

Tags: c++

How can I write the `Create()` function so that it works with derived classes too, enabling me to call `A a = A::Create();`?

```
class Base
{
public:
    
    using Id_t = int32_t;

    static std::shared_ptr<Base> Create()
    {
        static Id_t CurrentId = 0;
        return std::make_shared<Base>(CurrentId++);
    }
    
    Id_t GetId() const { return Id; }
    
private:
    
    Base(Id_t ObjectId) : Id{ObjectId} {}
    
    Id_t Id;
};

class A : public Base
{
};
```

Comment: Are you talking about a `clone()` function?

Comment: I'm getting some [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) vibes from this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Read up on *object slicing*.   Search the internet for "C++ object slicing example".

Comment: `static std::shared_ptr<Base> Create() { static Id_t CurrentId = 0; if (CurrentId > 3) return std::make_shared<A>(CurrentId++); return std::make_shared<Base>(CurrentId++); }`

Comment: I actually just want all child classes derived from Base to be created with a new ID, and I want to return a pointer to this child class.

Comment: Does the constructor absolutely have to be private? It can be a bit of a pain in the butt to deal with that when using `std::make_shared`. Here's a simple [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rPTrbhhTq) using a public constructor. Instead of externally supplying the ID during construction, you can calculate it during member-initialization.

Comment: @paddy In your example, I think it would be more illuminating to not use auto for the shared pointers; also, I would let `Create()` make return a shared_ptr of the actually created type, i.e. `static std::shared_ptr<Derived> Create()`. Due to shared_ptr's covariance, one can still use it to initialize a `shared_ptr<Base>` with it. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Evj3a8bv9) is a minimally modified variation of your code.

Comment: Why is there a `Base::Create()`? The reason for it (if my guess is accurate) would be a detail that could make your question stand out from others, but only if you describe it in the text of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something as simple as the following, which puts a static int variable in the base class constructor and uses it to initialize `obj_id`. Despite `c` being of type `B`, it calls the base class constructor, so gets a unique numeric id.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int obj_id;

    A() { 
        static int id = 0;
        obj_id = id;
        id++;
    }
};

struct B : public A { };

int main() {
    A a;
    A b;
    B c;

    std::cout << a.obj_id << ", " 
              << b.obj_id << ", "
              << c.obj_id << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach where the Create method is a function template in the baseclass that can create the derived classes and do the administration.  Like this :

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
public:
    using Id_t = std::int32_t; // don't forget to add namespace std here.

    // Use a function template to create types of a specific base class
    // the whole std::enable_if_t checks at compile time if the type_t is derived from Base
    // a pattern called SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error)
    template <typename type_t>
    static auto Create() 
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, type_t>, std::unique_ptr<type_t>>
    {
        // unique ownership is usually more likely
        return std::make_unique<type_t>(Base::get_next_id()); 
    }

    Id_t GetId() const
    {
        return Id;
    }

private:
    // make constructor private to prevent direct instantiation (Create should be used)
    explicit Base(const Id_t ObjectId) :
        Id{ ObjectId }
    {
    }   

    // this approach is thread-safe and
    // will avoid having a static member variable (a global)
    // now next_id will be initalized on first use
    // and its initialization will not depend on library load order
    static auto get_next_id() -> Base::Id_t
    {
        static Base::Id_t next_id = 0;
        return next_id++;
    }

    Base(Id_t ObjectId) :
        Id{ ObjectId }
    {
    }

    Id_t Id;
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class C
{
};

int main()
{
    auto a = Base::Create<A>();
    //auto a = Base::Create<C>(); <-- will not compile because C is not direved from Base
    return 0;
}
```